# How do I resize scrollview so that everything fits on-screen?

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'd like the ad to be on the bottom so that it's on-screen, and I'd like to shrink the `scrollview` or top-level `linearlayout` so that everything can fit on screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".DisplayMagic">

    <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/notice"
                android:text="@string/notice"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/magic_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notice"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_uri_message"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@string/test_value"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tags_box"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tags_box"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_uri_message"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This was working before I added `AdView`, but I'm not quite sure where I messed it up.

In this case, `@string/test_value` is just long dummy text to force the `scrollview` to be large:

```
    Ads are an effective and easy way to earn revenue from your apps. Google AdMob is
    a smart monetization platform for apps that helps you to maximize revenue from ads and in-app purchases. More
    than 1 million apps use Google AdMob to generate a reliable revenue stream, with more than $1 billion paid to
    developers. All you need to do is sign up for Google AdMob, and then use the Google Mobile Ads SDK to place ads
    in your app with just a few lines of code. You get paid quickly in your local currency (where available), with
    no wire fees charged by Google AdMob. Also, Google AdMob’s integration with Google Play services pushes
    automatic performance improvements to Android apps without additional SDK changes.Well-placed, well-targeted ads
    in apps, particularly free apps, can achieve good click-through rates while preserving the app’s user
    experience. It’s easy to add the code to deliver ads, and Google AdMob takes care of the rest: finding and
    delivering relevant ads to your app from any of Google’s advertiser demand across Google AdMob, Google Ads, and
    the Authorized buyers. This range of advertising sources—coupled with free, industry-leading mediation—achieves
    high CPMs and excellent fill rates, automatically helping to improve your earnings.
```

Is `wrap_content` not supposed to resize the `scrollview` or did I make a mistake in the layout somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you just embed the ScrollView and AdView inside a RelativeLayout when the AdView is android:layout_alignParentBottom=true  with height wrap_content and the scrollView fill be of height match parent with constraint to be above the AdView?  Unless I'm not getting the whole scenario well...

Comment: @Gil I'm certainly open to the idea, but I haven't quite figured out how to make that work

Comment: @Gil the documentation seems to agree with you, I'm just still not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I'll update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this xml code: I am using constraint layout with `ScrollView` and `AdView` with attributes match constraint which allows `ScrollView` to set it self with respect to its linked constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notice"
        android:text="@string/notice"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/magic_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" 
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">
    
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_uri_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/gen_text"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tags_box"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tags_box"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"     
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_uri_message"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"     
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you walk me through what you changed? Also, is it considered good practice to have multiple `ConstraintLayouts`? I changed the inner `constraintlayout` to a linear layout, and it looks perfect.

Comment: I just changed height attribute of scrollview to match constraint from design tab which is equavilent to 0dp and changed few constraints with respect to their views to adjust as your requirments. you can use any nested layout i.e(Linear, Relative, Constraint) but the best practice is to use minimum or least nested layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the complication of ConstraintLayout?  If I understand you correctly, you can achieve what you want by simplifying the layout to a linear layout and using layout weight to size the ScrollView, i.e.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DisplayMagic">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/notice"
            android:text="@string/notice"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/magic_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_uri_message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/test_value"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tags_box" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This gives a notice at the top and an ad at the bottom with the rest of the area between for the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
      android:layout_height="0dp"
```

change just that alredy so